# SpeechRecognizer not using Google API

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I was wondering if it´s possible that when using SpeechRecognizer class methods, you can use other voice transcription tool instead of Google's, and in case it is, how to proceed.

Ty!

Answer (score 0):

I searched and found this post from google, look through https://www.guidearea.com/pocketsphinx-continuous-speech-recognition-android-tutorial/